# Evaluating the usefulness of [evaluate] and [evaluation] tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[evaluate](/questions/tagged/evaluate) has 154 questions with no tag wiki. The question include:

- [jQuery - calculate a responsive margin for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982442/jquery-calculate-a-responsive-margin-for-an-element)
- [evaluate stripos(), what is the difference between !== FALSE and === TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382466/evaluate-stripos-what-is-the-difference-between-false-and-true)
- [casperJS Can't find variable : $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076750/casperjs-cant-find-variable)

All have to do with evaluating some variable/value, etc.

Then [evaluation](/questions/tagged/evaluation) has 386 questions with a broad tag wiki:

> Anything related to evaluation of expressions, i.e. the process used to determine the value of expressions in a running program.

Hmm..ok.  This has questions like:

- [How to evaluate an Haskell expression immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267344/how-to-evaluate-an-haskell-expression-immediately)
- [What does "top-level evaluation" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162108/what-does-top-level-evaluation-mean)
- [How does C# evaluate lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984678/how-does-c-sharp-evaluate-lambda-expressions)
- [How mahout's recommendation evaluator works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480004/how-mahouts-recommendation-evaluator-works)

Questions couldn't be tagged solely with either [evaluate](/questions/tagged/evaluate) or [evaluation](/questions/tagged/evaluation), which leads me to believe that these are tags to be burninated.

What should be done with these tags...burninated? Do they have a valid use that I might be missing?

Comment: Clearly, the actual problem here is just that there is no tag Wiki ;)

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn Clearly that is the only problem here. :)

Comment: Needs more evaluate. Could we get a tag on meta for this?